# Passing subobjects in JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to pass a JSON string to my PHP script, but I am unsure of how to build the string in a way that considers there could be 0 or more telephones, emails and faxes.

Here is an example of what my string looks like:

```
{"mode": "ADD_CONTACT", "id": 316, "firstname": "", "lastname": "", "telephones": {"teltype": 1, "telnumber": "234523453245", "isprimary": 0, "teltype": 4, "telnumber": "657567567567", "isprimary": 0}}
```

The problem is that my script only gives me the last phone number, presumably because the JSON parameter names are the same, so what format should I use to achieve what I want? I would like to avoid sticking incremental numbers on the end of the parameter names i.e. "telnumber1", "telnumber2" etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array (which can be empty):

```
{..., "telephones": [{"teltype": 1, "telnumber": "234523453245", ...}, {...}]}
```

Example:

```
$json = 
  '{"telephones": [' .
    '{"teltype": 1, "telnumber": "222222222222"}, ' .
    '{"teltype": 1, "telnumber": "111111111111"}' .
  ']}';
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

```
Array
(
    [telephones] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [teltype] => 1
                    [telnumber] => 222222222222
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [teltype] => 1
                    [telnumber] => 111111111111
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `telephones` et. al. should be arrays of objects rather than just a single object. An array starts with `[` and ends with `]`, e.g.:

```
"telephones": [
    {"teltype": 1, "telnumber": "234523453245", "isprimary": 0},
    {"teltype": 4, "telnumber": "657567567567", "isprimary": 0}
],
```

Arrays can be empty when necessary:

```
"telephones": []
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the multiple telephone numbers as an array:

```
{
    "mode": "ADD_CONTACT", "id": 316, "firstname": "", "lastname": "", 
    "telephones": 
    [
        {"teltype": 1, "telnumber": "234523453245", "isprimary": 0}, 
        {"teltype": 4, "telnumber": "657567567567", "isprimary": 0}
    ]
}
```

You'll obviously need to modify your server side script to expect an array for "telephones".